# Implication following from equation in polar form.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

In my book they have the expression

$$r'=r(1-r^2)-B\sin\theta$$

where $B$ is an arbitrary constant and conclude that it implies that for $r(r^2-1) > |B|+1$ the derivative $r'<-1$. How? Where does the $|B|+1$ come from?

Comment: From $-1\leq\sin\theta\leq 1$ with both bounds attainable.

Comment: Yes but shouldnt we then just have $|B|\cdot 1?$

Comment: You have the inequality $r'<-1.$  Put the $-1$ on the other side.